# How do I convert this delegate into a function?

Tags: c#

I have this delegate:

```
Func<Employee, string> format = e =>
     string.Format( "{0} - {1}, {2}",
       e.Number, e.LastName, e.FirstName
);
```

I'm going to use it in two different methods the same way, instead of repeating the code, I want to create a private method to handle this. How can I create a private method that do exactly the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static string FormatEmployee(Employee e)
{
    return string.Format( "{0} - {1}, {2}", e.Number, e.LastName, e.FirstName);
}
```

But really this sounds like it should be a method in the `Employee` class, or if you don't have access to edit that class then you can make it an extension method.

```
public static string FormatEmployee(this Employee e)
{
    return string.Format( "{0} - {1}, {2}", e.Number, e.LastName, e.FirstName);
}
```

Comment: thank you! I was over complicating the code. Thank you all for the answers

Answer (score 1):

```
private string FormatEmployee(Employee e) 
{
return string.Format("{0} - {1}, {2}",
       e.Number, e.LastName, e.FirstName);
}
```

?

Answer (score 1):

A func is a method that take one input and returns an output.

```
private string MethodName(Employee e)
{
    return string.Format("{0} - {1}, {2}",
         e.Number, e.LastName, e.FirstName);

}
```

Note that you can also use the [statement lambda](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687(v=vs.110).aspx)  instead of a lambda expression.  The statement lambda has the same method body as the named one above.

```
e => {
         return string.Format( "{0} - {1}, {2}",
              e.Number, e.LastName, e.FirstName);
     }
```

Comment: Your "anonymous function" is in fact using a lambda, not an anonymous function.

Comment: The change is purely stylistic; it has no effect on the code though, so I don't even know why you're bringing it up.

Comment: @Servy thanks for the input.  I finally found the source for the point I was trying to make (a single line expression vs a block statement).

Comment: But the OP only has a single expression; why would he need to use a statement lambda?